# Prove that if $x,y,z>0$ and $xyz=1$ then $\frac{1}{x+y+1} + \frac{1}{y+z+1} + \frac{1}{x+z+1}\leq \frac{3}{x+y+z}$

Tags: inequality

I read from the Internet that one can prove the following inequality using the rearrangement inequality: If  $x,y,z>0$ and $xyz=1$ then

$$\frac{1}{x+y+1} + \frac{1}{y+z+1} + \frac{1}{x+z+1}\leq \frac{3}{x+y+z}$$

Can anyone show me the details? Or if the rearrangement inequality can't solve it, what kind of proof the inequality has?

Comment: Probably you mean to write $xyz=1$.

Comment: @LandonCarter True. I edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply by $x+y+z$ to get
$$
\sum_{cyc}\frac{x+y+z}{x+y+1}=3+\sum_{cyc}\frac{z-1}{x+y+1}
$$
Furthermore we have
$$
\sum_{cyc}\frac{z-1}{x+y+1}≥\frac{1}{3}\left(\sum_{cyc}(z-1)\right)\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x+y+1}\right)=\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}-1\right)\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x+y+1}\right)≥0
$$
Where we used the inequality on equally ordered sequences ($z-1,x-1,y-1$ are ordered in the same sense as $\frac{1}{x+y+1},\frac{1}{y+z+1},\frac{1}{z+x+1}$) and AM-GM. So in fact, the reversed inequality is true:
$$
\sum_{cyc}\frac{x+y+z}{x+y+1}=3+\sum_{cyc}\frac{z-1}{x+y+1}≥3\implies\\
\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x+y+1}≥\frac{3}{x+y+z}
$$